# What does "it" in "with it" refer to?

Tags: serenity

In *Serenity* (2005), Malcolm crew make a last stand against the Reavers:

> Zoe: How much ammo do we have?
>
> Jayne: Three, four max, and my swinging cod. That's all.
>
> Inara: The lift isn't moving.
>
> Zoe: When they come, try to plug the hole with **it**.

What does "it" in "with it" refer to?

Comment: One of those moments when it's worth checking the subtitles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The object here is the Reavers. Since Zoe's objective is to prevent her crew being swarmed, and with ammo being mighty scare, she's telling Jayne to intentionally allow some of the Reavers to get through the door *before killing 'em*, thus preventing the others from getting through as easily because they'll need to climb over their fallen comrades to do so.

> **Problem was, them Reavers would be getting through the door, which was exactly what they didn't want.**
>
> "They're gonna get in," Zoe said.
>
> Kaylee sounded like hell when she said, "Can close it—from—outside—"
>
> Zoe tried to stand up, but couldn't. "No one's coming back from that. How much ammo do we have?"
>
> Jayne shook his head. "We got three ful cartridges and my swingin' cod. That's al ."
>
> Inara had run over to the elevator and had hit the button about sixty times. "Lift isn't moving."
>
> Fixing Jayne with one of those looks of hers, Zoe said, **"When they come, try to plug the hole with 'em."**
>
> <sub><sup>**[Serenity: Official Novelisation](https://firefly.fandom.com/wiki/Serenity_(novelization))**</sup></sub>

Comment: I think he could mean the weapon which kills the reavers. If he meant what you suggest, I think he would say, as you posted, "them" (or em). It is the weapon which fires the remaining ammo. The hole is the elevator shaft perhaps.

Comment: @releseabe - In both the [screenplay](https://imsdb.com/scripts/Serenity.html) and [novelisation](https://firefly.fandom.com/wiki/Serenity_(novelization)) the word she uses is 'em (them), not it - "When they come, try to plug the hole with 'em...", strongly implying that she means the Reavers. He doesn't need to be told to shoot the baddies, so she's clearly giving him orders about battle tactics.

Comment: The hole here is the still-open door. "*Problem was, them Reavers would be getting through the door, which was exactly what they didn't want.*"

Comment: He knows to shoot the reavers but Mal is emphasizing a tactic. But the screenplay and book I defer to.